# Сan't launch headless mod with chrome profiles in Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to use chrome browser in headless mode with the user-data-dir argument, but it doesn't work. I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1204, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1176, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1147, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 940, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/ritan/Desktop/python/twitter-Automatization/main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from config import LoggerConfig
  File "/home/ritan/Desktop/python/twitter-Automatization/config.py", line 43, in <module>
    class DriverConfig:
  File "/home/ritan/Desktop/python/twitter-Automatization/config.py", line 58, in DriverConfig
    driver = uc.Chrome(options=chrome_options, seleniumwire_options=options)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/ritan/Desktop/python/twitter-Automatization/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/seleniumwire/undetected_chromedriver/webdriver.py", line 61, in __init__
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ritan/Desktop/python/twitter-Automatization/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/undetected_chromedriver/__init__.py", line 466, in __init__
    super(Chrome, self).__init__(
  File "/home/ritan/Desktop/python/twitter-Automatization/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 45, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "/home/ritan/Desktop/python/twitter-Automatization/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chromium/webdriver.py", line 56, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "/home/ritan/Desktop/python/twitter-Automatization/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 208, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities)
  File "/home/ritan/Desktop/python/twitter-Automatization/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/undetected_chromedriver/__init__.py", line 724, in start_session
    super(selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver.WebDriver, self).start_session(
  File "/home/ritan/Desktop/python/twitter-Automatization/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 292, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, caps)["value"]
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/ritan/Desktop/python/twitter-Automatization/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 347, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/ritan/Desktop/python/twitter-Automatization/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 229, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot connect to chrome at 127.0.0.1:41763
from chrome not reachable
```

**Anyway, headless works without user-data-dir and vice versa.**

Here is my config:

```py
from seleniumwire import undetected_chromedriver as uc
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

class DriverConfig:
    options = {
        'proxy': {
            'http': PROXY
        }  
    }
    chrome_options = uc.ChromeOptions()
    chrome_options.add_argument('--headless=new')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu') 
    chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox') 
    chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
    chrome_options.add_argument("--ignore-ssl-errors=yes")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--ignore-certificate-errors")
    chrome_options.add_argument(f"user-agent={os.getenv('USER_AGENT')}")
    chrome_options.add_argument('user-data-dir=/home/ritan/.config/google-chrome/Kitty')
    
    driver = uc.Chrome(options=chrome_options, seleniumwire_options=options)
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 7)
```

I use selenium-wire library to set up auth proxy and chromedriver from undetected-driver library.

Сould there be any alternatives?
I need headless mode to improve optimization, because i use some sessions and with a gui it's too heavy. Also i have to use user-data-dir for managing accounts with different data, mostly cookies.

I will be very grateful for your help.